# html5mode Angular giving exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a website in Angular 1.5.5 and want to have pretty url (without #). Following the instructions on some other posts, I added `Html5mode` to be router along with base url in the index.html

```
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    <base href="innovationglobal">
```

However, I get the following exception :

> Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://home/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://localhost:8080'.
>       at Error (native)
>       at Yf.k.url (lib/1.5.5/angular.min.js:47:311)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the stack trace from an unminified angular lib, but my guess is it has something to do with the base href not matching. Have you tried `<base href="/" />` ?

Comment: What does your `base` tag look like? The error is due to cross origin protection, because "home" and "localhost" are different domains.

Comment: Also, the `.hashPrefix(...)` isn't necessary if you're using `.html5Mode(true)`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried using <base href="/">, but that doesn't load my css, js files because of path issues. I have <base href="app"> in my project, and I can see the home page loaded properly, but with exceptions. The url in my local is something like http://localhost:8080/app/leadership/

Comment: are you using jquery mobile?

Comment: No, I am not using JQuey mobile

Comment: @C14L, maybe thats the issue. I am using ui-router to support multiple pages. However, after adding baseurl, the states don't work

Comment: `<base href="innovationglobal">` doesn't look like a valid base url. It should be an absolute URL, starting with a `/` or a `https://...`.

Comment: @C14L, thanks for the update. I fixed my base url to <base href="/innovationglobal/">and updated  templateUrl in the router configuaration, and things looks good. However, when I refresh the page I get HTTP Status 404 . Is there anything else I need to setup for html5mode to work properly?

Comment: @anj2411 You need to set up your webserver to handle those URLs. See my answer that explains more in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing your  tag to an absolute URL or path

```
<base href="innovationglobal">
```

either by adding `/` or `https://`

```
<base href="/innovationglobal/">
```

now when you reload the page, the browser will send a request to the server for your current path: `/innovationglobal/`

You need to set up your server to handle that path --and any other path your Angular app may put into the browser address bar. That could be `/innovationglobal/users/` or `/innovationglobal/products/detail/` etc.

Because the user may press `F5` to reload on any page they are viewing. And that would take control away from your Angular app, and send the request for that URL to the server.

So you need to set up your server with a catch-all. Whatever the path in the address bar, your server should reply with the `index.html` of your Angular app.

But careful, you need to make an exception for your static assets (files like .js and .css). For nginx, that would looks somewhat like this:

```
location = /static/ {
    alias /var/www/static/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location /innovationglobal/ {
    root /var/www/innovationglobal;
    try_files $uri /app/index.html =404;
}
```

Depending on the web server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enable `html5Mode` without using a base:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```